# SwiftUI Compact Font

Tags: ios, swiftui, typography

How do I use the compact style from the system font?

I thought I would be something like:

```
font(Font.system(size: 21, style: .compact))
```

[image: SF Compact Display]

Comment: Your screenshot shows "font names"... there is no `compact` font style.

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
Text("Hello World")
    .h1()
```

Extension:

```
extension Text {
    func h1() -> Text {
        self
            .foregroundColor(Color.init(hex: "#FFFFFF", alpha: 1.0))
            .font(.custom("SF Pro Display", size: 80))
    }
}
```

or

```
Text("Hello World")
    .font(.custom("SF Pro Display", size: 80))
```